# Tensorflow takes >1 min on first run on video card with 5.0 compute capability

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running tensorflow 0.8.0 for python3 (pip installation), and the following file `test.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf                                                         

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([1], dtype=tf.int32)                               
b = tf.to_float(a)                                                              

with tf.Session():                                                              
    b.eval()
```

... takes more than a minute to run:

```
$time python3 test.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:900] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 860M
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0195
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.61GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:755] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 860M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)

real    1m6.985s
user    1m6.700s
sys 0m1.480s
```

I should mention other tensorflow programs seem to work fine, e.g.

```
$time python3 -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional
```

takes under 4 minutes.

Edit:

```
$cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt 
CUDA Version 7.5.18

$ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.4.0.7
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.4 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn_static.a
```

Comment: What if you disable GPU with `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""` ? I've seen some people waiting 6 minutes due to "PTX->SASS compilation", but that should've been fixed with upgrade to CUDA 7.5

Comment: This might be bad combination of video card/driver/CUDA version/CuDNN version, if you file a bug, please include that info

Comment: Thanks! I will try to reinstall tenorflow/cuda/cudnn. I edited the question.

Comment: Indeed the gpu configuration is the problem, If I add `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` it runs ok.

Answer (score 5):

I think your GPU GTX 860M is a sm_50 device. The default TensorFlow binary supports sm_35 and sm_52 by default. That means your binary only has PTX, and the Cuda runtime has to JIT them into SASS on the first run of that kernel, and that takes one minute or so. But they should be cached in later runs, unless the caching was explicitly disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The first call to eval() or run() is typically much slower than subsequent calls since it needs to setup the session. Subsequent calls to eval/run are typically much faster.