# How to build CUDA JIT caches for all available kernels in TensorFlow programmatically?

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, nvidia

I encountered the "first-run slow-down" problem with GTX 1080 cards and nvidia-docker as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842169/).

I'm using the TensorFlow build from [its official pip package](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl) and a custom docker image based on nvidia-docker's Ubuntu 16.04 base image.

How do I make TensorFlow to load (and build JIT caches) all registered CUDA kernels programmatically in a Dockerfile? (rather than manually building TensorFlow using `TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES` environment variable)

Comment: That's quite interesting. Could you post on our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page? If there's something we can do to alleviate that, either in further instructions, or in the code, then it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy way to achieve this since CUDA runtime implicitly, lazily compiles missing cubin from the given kernel sources [as discussed here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/224).

Solved this problem by rebuilding TensorFlow by myself, with some helper scripts to detect current CUDA/GPU configs and generate required TensorFlow configuration parameters ([detect-cuda.py](https://github.com/lablup/sorna-repl/blob/master/python3-tensorflow-gpu/detect-cuda.py), [build-tensorflow.sh](https://github.com/lablup/sorna-repl/blob/master/python3-tensorflow-gpu/build-tensorflow.sh)).

Comment: Both links are broken.