# TensorFlow tf.nn.conv2d parallelization

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow

Is there a way of parallelizing tf.nn.conv2d operation in TensorFlow using GPU when the batch size equals to 1?

I want to give only one image to my CNN and I want the computations to be parallelized on a GPU. As far as I understand, TensorFlow does not parallelize efficiently for a batch size of 1 as the process is faster on CPU.

Comment: How large is the image? The advice for batch sizes is to fill up your GPU memory, so if the GPU is going to have something to do then ideally the single image you're interested in would be about that large. If it isn't, then the question is: what are you trying to optimize for? If it's something like serving latency, transferring to the GPU one at a time may be just too much overhead.

Comment: Both CPU and GPU are going to be inefficient for batch size 1. This batch size means that network parameters have to be loaded into fast memory (registers/cache) for each example.

Comment: The size of the tensors I'm giving during testing is 3 times larger than the tensors of training batches but it's 15 times slower. (Even with backpropagation during training) If it's a matter of overhead, would not it be a problem during training, too?

Comment: I just realized that if I run the same thing with random images as inputs, it becomes much faster. Turns out, the first run is 5-6 times slower. I am not completely sure why it happens though.

Comment: the first run is usually slower because some things are initialized during the first run

Comment: ie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842169/tensorflow-takes-1-min-on-first-run-on-video-card-with-5-0-compute-capability/36871892#36871892

Comment: Yeah, that simply explains it, thanks